# controllerAs in directive's link function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I created a d3 barchart directive using scope in the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/yF8H9i8tyu1o2xJCN9bV

with controller having chartData in the scope.

```
.controller('d3Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.chartData = [10,20,30,40,50];
    }])
```

and I have a bi-directional association of chartData with directive's isolated scope

```
          scope: {
              chartData: '='
          },
          restrict: 'EA',
          replace: false,
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var data = attrs.chartData.split(',');
            var d3 = $window.d3;
            var chart = d3.select(elem[0]);

            chart
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "chart")

                //returns an array of all <div>...</div> elements in div
                .selectAll("div")
                    .data(scope.chartData)
                .enter()
                    .append("div")
                    .transition().ease("elastic")
                    .style("width", function (d) {
                        return d + "%"
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d + "%"
                    });
```

and the associated directive is as follows

```
<bar-chart chart-data="chartData"></bar-chart>
```

This is working fine. But, I am trying to do the same using "controllerAs"

I tried making some changes, but, it is not working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eIRkAtfJx9rlWN5LtllC

I changed the controller's scoped chartData to this

```
 .controller('d3Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var self = this;
      self.chartData = [10,20,30,40,50];
    }])
```

using controllerAs and bindToDirective options for directive

```
      scope: { },
      controllerAs: 'barCtrl',
      controller: function() { },
      bindToDirective: {
        chartData: '='
      },
```

when trying to get chartData, it is saying barCtrl is not defined.

```
.selectAll("div")
.data(barCtrl.chartData)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly doing some stuff in your `controller As` code.

1) You need to specify 2 way binding via the `scope` property of the settings not `bindToDirective`, there is no recognized property like that in the directive settings.

2) Need to use `bindToController` flag to specify any scope bound 2 way bound properties to be added to the controller instance and not directly on the scope. Though it is possible that you can do `bindToController:{chartData:"="}` it is not documented in the official doc and hence i would not recommend doing that way since it could be removed as well in the upcoming versions.

3) You can use the 4th argument to the link function as the controller instance and refer to it inside your linking function.

So it would look like

```
.directive('barChart', ['$window', function($window) {
        var myDirective = {
          controllerAs: 'barCtrl',
          controller: angular.noop,
          bindToController:true, //<-- Need to specify bound values to be added to the controller instance
          scope: {   //Need to use scope not bindToDirective
            chartData: '='
          },
          restrict: 'EA',
          replace: false,//if it is false you don't need it
          //use the 4th argument as the controller instance
          link: function (scope, elem, attrs, barCtrl) {

          }
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4WxgllDOsEfML9E91cm9?p=preview)**

Comment: I was looking at toddMotto's blogpost: http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/ and it says this is something new
        `scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            name: '='
        },`

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon Ok, how is it different? I dont think you followed stuffs properly perhaps? it suggests using ` bindToController:{
            chartData: '='
          },` which is undocumented and i would n't be doing that. Since it is not documented it could so happen that that is removed.

Comment: I don't think it is any different. But, he mentioned that it is preferred way of doing it. `(preferred), refactor bindToController: true into an Object, moving scope: {} properties across to it for clarity. Fixes same as example two, but adds clarity for other developers working/revisiting the piece of code.`

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon it is, you were using `bindToDirective` and not `bindToController` Also you cannot just magically get controller instance in your link function, it is nothing but an alias added on the scope as a property.